# How to pick file deletions, creations and moves from a git branch efficiently?

Tags: git

Assume that I was searching for a fix of an issue and trying multiple solutions that I lost track of or changed more than one thing and the changes ought to become more than one commit. I then stored everything into a branch `temp` with

```
git checkout -b temp master && git add . && git commit -m "pick piece by piece"
```

Now, the only thing I can think of to pick the changes piece by piece is `git difftool` (and I might be wrong at this point already) which does the job for changes to files. If the changes I stored in `temp` include file deletions, creations or moves, `meld` and assume every other `git difftool` as well displays deletions and insertions against `/dev/null` on one side and moves as one file deletion plus one file insertion.

In order to pick them from the branch it'd be much more convenient to be able to choose a file operation like accept the deletion, insertion, etc., similar to merging, next to an option to view the file which has been deleted, created or moved.

My current approach of deleting, moving or copying in a separate terminal is inconvenient because I have to switch terminals while `git difftool` is in progress. And for files which only exist on the diffed branch, I have to copy the content from the difftool and paste it into a file or abort the diff, checkout `temp`, copy the file to temporary location, checkout `master` again and move the file where it belongs.

Merging or cherry-picking is not an option afaiu since I don't want to have all changes of the commit, but select them line-by-line and file-operation-by-file-operation.

I'm sure that there's an awesome new thing to learn about `git` again.

Comment: I actually don't see a problem statement here.  Can you include one?  Take 1-2 sentences and clearly tell us what the problem is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added a paragraph about my approach explaing what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a soft reset back to the head of the master branch, which will maintain your current working directory but reset the branch and index back to master.

`git reset --soft master`

Everything will be back the way it was before your commit. You can then add individual files.

`git add <file>`

Add parts of individual files.

`git add --patch <file>`

Or go whole hog and use full interactive add.

`git add --interactive`

See the full chapter on interactive staging in the [Pro Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) for an in depth guide.